Global Hyperbolicity of Spacetimes implying Connectedness
I am currently working on a problem and right now I want to show that the global hyperbolicity of a spacetime M implies, that M is connected. Therefore, I assumed the following:
We could write $M$ as the disjoint union of two spacetimes, such that $M = M_1 \sqcup M_2$. Consequently, $M_1$ and $M_2$ inherit the global hyperbolicity of $M$, and hence admit Cauchy surfaces $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ such that $\Sigma = \Sigma_1 \sqcup \Sigma_2$ is a Cauchy surface in $M$. Assume $p \in M_1$ and $q \in M_2$ such that $q$ is in the causal future of $p$.
Therefore, we can find a causal inextendible curve $\gamma$ in $M$ connecting $p$ and $q$. Since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are globally hyperbolic, $\gamma$ would intersect $\Sigma_1$ in $M_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ in $M_2$ exactly once, and hence $\Sigma$ twice. This contradicts the global hyperbolicity of $M$, as any causal inextendible curve should intersect $\Sigma$ exactly once.
I am not sure about, wether this approach is sufficient for showing that M is connected or not and appreaciate any comment on that.

Or it may contradict your other assumption, namely that $J^+(p) \cap M_2 \neq \varnothing$.

Usually, non-connected spacetimes are not of great physical interest (no physical communication is possible between two components), so this issue is not physically relevant at first glance. However, it makes sense from the mathematical-physics viewpoint.
A time-oriented spacetime (a smooth Lorentzian manifold with time orientation) $(M,g,O_t)$ is globally hyperbolic if there exists a set $S$ such that it meets exactly once every inextendible future-directed timelike (smooth) curve.  $S$ is said Cauchy surface of $(M,g,O_t)$.
Minkowski spacetime $M^n$ is globally hyperbolic. Every open diamond in $M^n$ with a basis given by an open ball $B$ of finite radius in the rest space $\Sigma^{n-1} \equiv \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is globally hyperbolic as well, and its basis $B$ is a Cauchy surface. All that is very well known.
Then consider  the pair of open diamonds  in $M^2\equiv \mathbb{R}^2$ with bases $(-2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ along the $x$ axis. Their union is globally hyperbolic since $(-2,1) \cup (1,2)$ is a  Cauchy surface: it is a set which intersects every inextendible timelike curve in the spacetime exactly once. This spacetime is not connected, however.
Since the topology of a globally hyperbolic spacetime is always $\Sigma \times \mathbb{R}$, where $\Sigma$ is any Cauchy surface ($\Sigma$ is a $C^0$ embedded submanifold, and all Cauchy surfaces are homeomorphic, as well known), the spacetime is connected if and only if $S$ is connected.
